# Cleanse Postgres array of text

Tags: postgresql

I am moving over to using Postgres and text[] for keywords. I used csv strings before. As a result, my data is ugly and I have example of this.

```
{Tor," granite"," rock formations"," landscape"," people"," men"," 1920s"," 20th century"," climbing"}
```

Is there an *easy* way to trim and cleanse the data so it is more like this.

```
{Tor,granite,rock formations,landscape,people,men,1920s,20th century,climbing}
```

Comment: Is this just a varchar column?

Comment: Yes. `tags           | text[]                   |`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as this:

```
select replace( replace( yourField, '"', '' ), ', ', ',')
  from yourTable
```

The result will be:

```
{Tor,granite,rock formations,landscape,people,men,1920s,20th century,climbing}
```

See it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ea962/1